# Meteor.userId() not available in ConnectHandlers

Tags: meteor

I am trying to create a file upload feature in Meteor where a logged in user is able to upload a file to the server under a directory named after their username. I have the basics working but when I take it a step further by checking the logged in user ID, things start breaking. Specifically:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/upload/', function(req, res) {
    if (this.userId) {
        // Do cool stuff.
    } else {
        res.writeHead(500, {"content-type":"text/html"});
        res.end("this.userId = " + this.userId); // End the response.
    }
});
```

Result:

```
this.userId = undefined
```

And...

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/upload/', function(req, res) {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        // Do cool stuff.
    } else {
        res.writeHead(500, {"content-type":"text/html"});
        res.end("Meteor.userId() = " + Meteor.userId()); // End the response.
    }
});
```

Result:

```
Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.
    at Object.Meteor.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:19:1)
    at Object.Package [as handle] (packages/cool_package/upload.js:34:1)
    at next (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.2.0.19shc3d++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Function.app.handle (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.2.0.19shc3d++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:198:3)
    at Object.fn [as handle] (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.2.0.19shc3d++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:74:14)
    at next (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/webapp/.1.2.0.19shc3d++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.WebAppInternals.staticFilesMiddleware (packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:331:1)
    at packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:625:1
```

The code above is included in a Meteor package I'm developing. The package.js file specifies that the code should run on the server:

```
api.add_files("upload.js", "server");
```

So my questions are:

- What is the correct way to check the logged in user ID and username?
- Can this code be moved to an Iron Router route instead?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the line

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/upload/', function(req, res) {
```

Is Express.js or similar code -- if so, you have broken out of the Meteor frameowrk providing your own REST services etc.   If that is the case you also have to provide your own user management and authentication scheme for incoming REST calls, just as you would in any other bare-bones REST applications

Comment: Actually WebApp.connectHandlers.use uses official meteor API of the webapp package: https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html

Nevertheless you are right, that one has to code the auth stuff "by hand" in this case.